# A property of metric projection

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $Y$ be a complex Hilbert space, $X$ be a complex normed space and $A \in L(X,Y)$. Is it true that, for a given $g \in Y$ fixed, the condition $$||A\phi-g||\geq ||Af-g||$$
for every $\phi \in X$ implies that $Af=P_{\overline{\text{range} A}}g$?

I think so. Take $y \in \overline{\text{range} A}$ so that $y=\lim_nA\phi_n$. By continuity of $A$ we get $$||y-g||\geq ||Af-g||$$

This implies that $Af$ is a minimizer of the distance from $g$ to all elements $y$ of $\overline{\text{range} A}$. Hence $Af=P_{\overline{\text{range} A}}g$. Is this correct?

Comment: Seems ok to me.